# Use application icon for shortcut icons in WIX installer

Tags: .net, wix

My C#.net application has a .ico file in the Resources directory (e.g. MyProject/Resources/icon.ico),

I have created an installer using the WIX toolset.

When I install the application the icon shows in the top left of the window, but not on the task bar (show in taskbar is set to true in the application) and not along side the .exe

How do I reference the application icon in the wix xml source so it shows on the .exe file in Program Files and on the start menu?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to specify the Icon tag within your app menu Shortcut tag. Here's an example of the Icon tag:

```
    <Icon Id="MyIconID" SourceFile="..\PathToLogo\yourLogo.ico"></Icon>
```

Here's where you should put it:

```
<Shortcut Id="MyAppStartMenuShortcut" 
              Name="MyApp" 
              Description="My App description" 
              Target="[INSTALLFOLDER]MyAppPathMyApp.exe" 
              WorkingDirectory="MyApp">
              <Icon Id="MyIconID" SourceFile="..\PathToLogo\yourLogo.ico"></Icon>
    </Shortcut>
```

The path in the SourceFile is the path to the icon you want to import. Wix will take care of adding the icon to your installation file and also makes sure it gets shown in your Program Files.
Hope this helps!

Comment: That worked so thank you for putting me on the first step. However that is when I use the full path to the icon (C:\Users\tom\Documents\Project\Resources\icon.ico). When i distribute this application other users are not going to have access to my local machine so wouldn't be able to find the file. Can I point the source file to the resource of my main application at all?

Comment: I've updated my answer. Once again Wix takes care of this for you. Mind marking the answer as your accepted answer?

Comment: Aaah I see, so when the program is complied it packages the local resources into the installer?

Comment: Exactly, "SourceFile" simply points to the location of the resource you want to add, in this case a .ico file.

Comment: **Important** note for `MyIconID` in the example: **The ID has to end with ".ico"**, e.g. `MyIconID.ico`. Otherwise you get this compiler error: *"ICE50: The extension of Icon '...' for Shortcut '...' does not match the extension of the Key File for component '...'."*

Answer (score 0):

Did someone notice the problem with antiviruses when used exe file of built software as a icon file.
I have something like this:
`<Icon Id="icon.ico" SourceFile="$(var.....TargetDir)/SoftwareName.exe" />` and https://www.hybrid-analysis.com/ pointed my installer as a malicious (and pointed icon.ico as a dangerous file).

In the case I described, is the `icon.ico` the copy of `SoftwareName.exe` file? If it is, maybe there is a problem with missing cert signing of this file?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34953684)